# 404 errors in Experience Profile after upgrading to 8.2

Tags: upgrade, experience-profile

I had a functioning copy of Sitecore 8.1 Original release and I've been able to upgrade my CM, CD, Reporting, and Processing/Aggregation servers so that I don't get any obvious errors. However, now that I'm playing around a little bit in the CM instance, I'm getting some errors that I didn't see before. Right now whenever I try to view details of one of my anonymous users, I get a screen with a few errors. The screen looks like this:
[image: Generic Error List]

Being the clever person that I am, I decided to investigate the sitecore logs, which give me this very helpful information:

```
8468 16:46:24 ERROR The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.Datasources.Remote.RemoteReportDataSourceProxy.GetData(ReportDataQuery query)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.ExecuteQueryWithCache(ReportDataQuery query, ReportDataSource dataSource, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.GetData(String dataSourceName, ReportDataQuery query, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Processors.ExecuteReportingServerDatasourceQuery.CollectReportingServerData(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Processors.ExecuteReportingServerDatasourceQuery.Process(ReportProcessorArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.IntelController.Get(ViewParameters viewParams, Guid contactId, String viewId, String id)
```

I decide to try to figure out what the URLs are that are being asked for, and so I investigate the JavaScript Console and find that these requests are being made using AJAX:

```
http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/best-pattern-matches?&pageSize=3&pageNumber=1

http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/latest-events?&pageSize=1000000&pageNumber=1

http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/recent-campaigns?&pageSize=3&pageNumber=1

http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/journey?&pageSize=2000

http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/latest-statistics?&pageSize=1&pageNumber=1
```

I have no idea what these URLs are supposed to point to, so I'm not sure how to proceed. The stack trace isn't very helpful for helping to figure out what my next steps should be. The URLs look properly formed, but the links don't lead to anywhere.

How do I start figuring out what the problem is?

**UPDATE:**
Using the hints from the comments, I double-checked my settings in the `Sitecore.Xedb.Remote.Client.config` file and that was pointing to my Reporting server. Just for fun, I changed the IP address to a non-existent server, and got the same results. I also tried to navigate to this URL

```
http://MyReportingServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/latest-statistics?&pageSize=1&pageNumber=1
```

instead of

```
http://MyCMServerURL/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/b8a06f4c-a784-48cb-9d86-b6a2e0133974/intel/latest-statistics?&pageSize=1&pageNumber=1
```

and I was able to get valid information back from the browser. It would appear that everything is *almost* configured correctly, but maybe there is a new/changed setting that I've missed. I'd love to get some additional insight into what I might be missing. Thank you!

Comment: Search all configs for the "MyCMSServerUrl". If your reporting server is separated from the primary CM server, it might be in the Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Server.config or Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config. Either way there's a setting that has a default value that should be getting changed. ShowConfig.aspx will probably help reveal it too.

Comment: These URLs are the Sitecore Reporting API - a REST API Sitecore introduced to allow for retrieval of report data from the Reporting Server, possibly your xDB processing server.  The system is enabled/disabled/controlled through config (isn't everything).  Look for files like `Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config`, `Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.MarketingAssets.config` and `Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config` and settings like `<httpTransportFactory ... ><param desc="serviceUrl">...`

Comment: @PeteNavarra I have searched all of the ShowConfig.aspx and it doesn't have that URL anywhere in the config file.

Comment: @RichardHauer I've been through all of those config files, and even did a search for that serviceUrl, and I only found it in 1 place, and that is pointing to my reporting server.

Comment: Seems like the system is falling back to a default maybe. If the value isn't explicitly in config, that's really the only option. In which case we need to work out why it isn't reading your config settings. I assume you checked both the file *and* `showconfig.aspx`

Comment: Yes, @RichardHauer I did check both locations, and it is set properly in both places. I agree with your assessment, it would appear that the system is falling back to some sort of default. But trying to figure out why and how to get it to use my settings instead, that's the real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending quite a bit of time double-checking my configs (and opening up a Sitecore Support Ticket), I found out that there were 3 things that had messed me up. Hopefully, one of these things will be helpful to others!

1. Double/Triple check that your configs on your Reporting server are correct (not just your Content Management Server). It turns out that I had neglected to enable the `Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Server.config` file on the reporting server. As many times as I had checked, I had simply missed that step.
2. Make sure that your reporting server is actually up and running. It also turns out that I had mis-typed the port number for my SOLR instance on my reporting server, and so my reporting server wasn't actually running.
3. Although the JavaScript errors were coming back from my CM Server's address, the problem was actually on my **reporting** server.

I hope this will help someone else when they are trying to diagnose issues.